# Embed GTK/Glade Python Application in Web Page

Tags: python, gtk, embed, pygtk, glade

I've developed a Python program that has a GTK based GUI that I have made with the user interface builder software Glade. Since it is developed with Glade there is a '.glade' file as well as the actual Python file.

I'm wondering if there is a way of embedding this in a web page?

I've researched this a fair bit and I have found a couple of resources that mention how to do this with a GTK based GUI but they're not much help. Also, there is nothing that mentions involving a Glade file and so I'm not sure if this will affect it.

**UPDATE**

Here are the resources I found on the subject.

[Link 1](http://worldofgnome.org/running-gtk-apps-on-web-with-node-broadway/)

[Link 2](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html)

Also, not worried about any security issues as the endgame would be to run this locally.

Comment: Glade doesn't make any difference; it doesn't matter whether the GUI is created by reading a file or by making explicit calls. The hard part is mapping the Gtk+ GUI calls and events to HTML/DOM calls and events. You say you've found a couple of resources that mention how to do this, but I've never heard of anyone doing it, so maybe a link to those resources would help.

Comment: However, there is one workaround to this: You can embed an X11 server in a browser, or a VNC server that hosts an X11 server, and then just run the Gtk+ app against that X11 server. That can be useful for intranet uses, but I don't think it would be a good way to expose a Gtk+ app over the internet.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post above to include the links. Will take a look at embedding an X11 server now. Any suggestions towards a good guide?

Comment: If you're targeting GTK+ 3 then a slightly easier solution is to use the new "Broadway" backend which allows GTK+ to be served on a web page. The only caveat is that a single Broadway server can only talk to a single Broadway client at a time.